# MySQL JSON column speed

Tags: mysql, json

I'm working on a custom CRM for a client who wants "custom fields" which need to be completely dynamic on a per-user basis. I have considered EAV because I cannot simply add these columns to the table. However, after doing some digging, I have settled with using a JSON column in order to store the custom field values in key value pairs.

My concern is the speed of doing lookups on data in this JSON column. How can I ensure that queries which search or perform where's on values in this JSON column remain fast with large amounts of rows in the table?

Or is a JSON column not the ideal solution for this?

Comment: I think EAV would be better. MySQL encodes JSON data for easy parsing, but I don't think they're indexed.

Comment: See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index), it may be helpful.